# How fetch thumbnail image of taxonomy in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing a problem with fetching thumbnail images related to terms. Actually that taxonomies and terms are being added up through a feature of the theme. And that taxonomies are not related to any posts.
I have tried so far.

**Code**

```
global $dest_list, $trav_options, $post;
foreach( $dest_list as $dest ) {
     $image = get_taxonomy_image( $dest[term_id] );
```

I have also tried `get_tax_meta()` but it is also not working.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What theme is it?

Comment: Using Travelo Theme

Comment: Can you help me to understand how the custom posts have relation with custom taxonomies.

Comment: Defaults are related as wp_posts.postID => wp_term_relationships.object_id => wp_term_taxonomy.term_id => term

Comment: I have not found any post related to custom taxonomies

Comment: Actually i have added custom post categories and added thumbnail to the categories but i failed to find any relation in wp_postmeta.

Comment: You should ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer.

Comment: I suspect the theme has some custom functions that may help you - their documentation or support may help.

Comment: yeh i figured it out. thanks for help.